# Can I pause a training epoch [Keras/Python3/Spyder]?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, spyder

I am training a model in which a single epoch takes around 8 hours to finish. That is not quite a problem, I don't mind waiting, but since I am running this script on GPU, I was wondering if I can pause the execution when I need the GPUs for something else, resuming when ready.

I looked everywhere but found no solution. Spyder does not help since it only has a stop button to terminate whatever is running in the console.

I am running Python3 on Windows/Spyder.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I don't think this is possible, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to import asyncio library with the sleep module:

```py
from asyncio import sleep
sleep(sleepTime)
```

It will make an asynchrone sleep of your script